# converting lua file to csv or tsv or any excel database file

Tags: excel, csv, lua

I have a lua file that is a database of all my raids in World of Warcraft game. It is generated by an addon in the game and has the information of which player received which loot for which price.
Like this:

```
GDKPd_PotData = {
["playerBalance"] = {
},
["curPotHistory"] = {
},
["history"] = {
    {
        ["date"] = "Thu Apr 29 14:54:21 2021",
        ["note"] = false,
        ["items"] = {
            {
                ["bid"] = 225,
                ["item"] = "|cffa335ee|Hitem:19866::::::::60:::::::|h[Warblade of the Hakkari]|h|r",
                ["name"] = "Brighht",
            }, -- [1]
            {
                ["bid"] = 50,
                ["item"] = "|cff0070dd|Hitem:19907::::::::60:::::::|h[Zulian Tigerhide Cloak]|h|r",
                ["name"] = "Treasuredon",
            }, -- [2]
            {
                ["bid"] = 50,
                ["item"] = "|cffa335ee|Hitem:19897::::::::60:::::::|h[Betrayer's Boots]|h|r",
                ["name"] = "Sassysis",
            }, -- [3]
            {
                ["bid"] = 50,
                ["item"] = "|cff0070dd|Hitem:19895::::::::60:::::::|h[Bloodtinged Kilt]|h|r",
                ["name"] = "Yabmage",
            }, -- [4]
            {
                ["bid"] = 180,
                ["item"] = "|cffa335ee|Hitem:19856::::::::60:::::::|h[The Eye of Hakkar]|h|r",
                ["name"] = "Consti",
            }, -- [5]
            {
                ["bid"] = 100,
                ["item"] = "|cffa335ee|Hitem:19802::::::::60:::::::|h[Heart of Hakkar]|h|r",
                ["name"] = "Consti",
            }, -- [6]
            {
                ["bid"] = 300,
                ["item"] = "|cff0070dd|Hitem:22637::::::::60:::::::|h[Primal Hakkari Idol]|h|r",
                ["name"] = "Gnomepowah",
            }, -- [7]
            {
                ["bid"] = 220,
                ["item"] = "|cff0070dd|Hitem:22637::::::::60:::::::|h[Primal Hakkari Idol]|h|r",
                ["name"] = "Lockbik",
            }, -- [8]
            {
                ["bid"] = 110,
                ["item"] = "|cffa335ee|Hitem:20725::::::::60:::::::|h[Nexus Crystal]|h|r",
                ["name"] = "Aeto",
            }, -- [9]
        },
        ["size"] = 1285,
    }, -- [1]
```

My idea was to convert it into an excel where I could create statistics and graphics and manage the info.

I looked all through the web and couldn't find any program that would convert lua into any excel file formats (xls,csv,tsv)

Can anyone give me some ideas on how to best do this?

Comment: If you haven't found any online tools, you may need to write your own parser in VBA or possibly Power Query.

Comment: What would a CSV version of this data look like?

Comment: @lhf The idea is to have 5 columns: date, note, bid, item and name. So in the case of the first item it would be:
"Thu Apr 29 14:54:21 2021",false,225,"|cffa335ee|Hitem:19866::::::::60:::::::|h[Warblade of the Hakkari]|h|r","Treasuredon"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV and TSV is basically the same thing you just have a different delimiter.

Writing .xls or xlsx is a bit more complicated.

If you want to use xlsx you open a web brower and enter "lua xlsx" into any websearch. You'll find https://github.com/jmcnamara/xlsxwriter.lua  for example.

```
--
-- A simple example of some of the features of the xlsxwriter module.
--

local Workbook = require "xlsxwriter.workbook"

local workbook  = Workbook:new("demo.xlsx")
local worksheet = workbook:add_worksheet()

-- Widen the first column to make the text clearer.
worksheet:set_column("A:A", 20)

-- Add a bold format to use to highlight cells.
local bold = workbook:add_format({bold = true})

-- Write some simple text.
worksheet:write("A1", "Hello")

-- Text with formatting.
worksheet:write("A2", "World", bold)

-- Write some numbers, with row/column notation.
worksheet:write(2, 0, 123)
worksheet:write(3, 0, 123.456)

workbook:close()
```

Writing CSV or TSV is trivial. You just need to write the values to a file using [Lua's io library](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.8) and separate them by a comma or a tab.

Both solutions require you to traverse over your table recursively using a few for loops.

Comment: I never coded in lua, so I was just looking for an actual converter. I see now that I will have either to write something in lua or vba. You say the thing is trivial, however its lines and lines of tables and one of the columns is always the same value at the start. still trying to see how to go about writing it myself. but thx for the idea.

Comment: A converter would be difficult. You need to know the structure of a table and the output file to convert from one to another. So unless someone implemented one for the exact same problem as yours you won't find one.